# Codeigniter Noob problems

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am noob in CI and I can't insert a data in database, here is all I have done, it doesn't show me an error but i don't get a result,

admin.php (controller)

```
public function postnews(){

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            if ($ip == "my ip address"){

                session_start();

                if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
                    $this->load->view('admin-login');
                    die(0);
                    }

                if ($_SESSION['admin'] != 'loged'){
                    $this->load->view('admin-login');
                    die(0);
                    }

                if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 'loged'){

                    if (isset($_POST['title'])and isset($_POST['main-poster']) and isset($_POST['type']) and isset($_POST['year']) and isset($_POST['language'])and isset($_POST['platform'])and isset($_POST['publisher'])and isset($_POST['size'])and isset($_POST['graphics'])and isset($_POST['little-info'])and isset($_POST['full-info'])and isset($_POST['posters'])and isset($_POST['screenshots'])and isset($_POST['trailers'])and isset($_POST['gameplays'])and isset($_POST['author'])){

                        $title = $_POST['title'];
                        $main_poster = $_POST['main-poster'];
                        $type = $_POST['type'];
                        $year = $_POST['year'];
                        $language = $_POST['language'];
                        $platform = $_POST['platform'];
                        $publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
                        $size = $_POST['size'];
                        $graphics = $_POST['graphics'];
                        $little_info = $_POST['little-info'];
                        $full_info = $_POST['full-info'];
                        $posters = $_POST['posters'];
                        $screenshots = $_POST['screenshots'];
                        $trailers = $_POST['trailers'];
                        $gameplays = $_POST['gameplays'];
                        $autor = $_POST['author'];
                        $date = date("d.m.Y");

                        $this->load->model('Gamesmodel');
                        echo $this->Gamesmodel->PostArticle($title, $main_poster, $type, $year, $language, $platform, $publisher, $size, $graphics, $little_info, $full_info, $posters, $screenshots, $trailers, $gameplays, $autor, $date);

                    }else{
                        $this->load->view('postnews');
                    }

                }

            } else {
                $this->load->view('404.htm');
                die(0);
            }

    }
```

gamemodel.php model

```
<?php
class Gamesmodel extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function PostArticle($title, $main_poster, $type, $year, $language, $platform, $publisher, $size, $graphics, $little_info, $full_info, $posters, $screenshots, $trailers, $gameplays, $autor, $date)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO game-articles (id, title, type, year, language, platform, publisher, size, graphics, little-info, full-info, posters, screenshots, trailers, gameplays, date, author) VALUES ('' ,".$this->db->escape($title).",".$this->db->escape($main_poster).",".$this->db->escape($type).",".$this->db->escape($year).",".$this->db->escape($language).",".$this->db->escape($platform).",".$this->db->escape($publisher).",".$this->db->escape($size).",".$this->db->escape($graphics).",".$this->db->escape($little_info).",".$this->db->escape($full_info).",".$this->db->escape($posters).",".$this->db->escape($screenshots).",".$this->db->escape($trailers).",".$this->db->escape($gameplays).",".$this->db->escape($date).",".$this->db->escape($author).")";
        $this->db->query($sql);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
}
```

postnews.php view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Post News</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">
    <div style="margin:auto auto auto auto; width:800px; background-color:white; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center;">
        <form action="http://www.gameslib.net/admin/postnews" method="post"><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title" style="width:300px;" /><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="main poster" name="main-poster" style="width:300px;" /><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="type" name="type" style="width:300px;" /><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="year" name="year"/><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="language" name="language" style="width:300px;" /><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="platform" name="platform" style="width:300px;" /><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="publisher" name="publisher" style="width:300px;" /><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="size" name="size"/><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="graphics" name="graphics" style="width:300px;" /><br />
            <textarea name="little-info" placeholder="little-info" style="width:600px; height:100px;" ></textarea><br />
            <textarea name="full-info" placeholder="full-info" style="width:600px; height:200px;" ></textarea><br />
            <textarea name="posters" placeholder="posters" style="width:600px; height:50px;" ></textarea><br />
            <textarea name="screenshots" placeholder="screenshots" style="width:600px; height:50px;" ></textarea><br />
            <textarea name="trailes" placeholder="trailes" style="width:600px; height:50px;" ></textarea><br />
            <textarea name="gameplays" placeholder="gameplays" style="width:600px; height:50px;" ></textarea><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="author" name="author" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="P O S T"/><br />
            <input type="reset" value="reset"/><br />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me, I copied allmost everything to be shure I am not ignoring something,

Comment: Instead of setting each independent variable for each `$_POST` key, you should use `extract($_POST);`

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I wrote that I am noob, can you give me an example of it?

Comment: I did? Re-read my comment. Also, change all of the `and` to `&&`

Comment: ok, Is there anything else that should be changed, or can cause Error? this is same I think "and" and "&&"

Comment: Another tip would be to use http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html and the builtin $this->input->post('varname', TRUE); instead of going directly to $_POST[] since you get something that is sanitized that way. Also, keep AND in the code if you want to follow CI's coding-standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets start by clearing up your code. Instead of having to create each independent variable in your `if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 'loged')` method, you can use the function `extract();`. The `extract()` method creates a variable for each key in the provided array. Say you have the key `name` in the array `$_POST`, the extract method will create a variable named `name` for you. To retrieve the value, all you need to do is access the variable `$name`.

```
if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 'loged'){

    extract($_POST);

}
```

Secondly, you don't use the word `and` if you want to check more than one thing in an if statement, you use the following operand '&&'.

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['main-poster']) && isset($_POST['type']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['language']) && isset($_POST['platform']) && isset($_POST['publisher']) && isset($_POST['size']) && isset($_POST['graphics']) && isset($_POST['little-info']) && isset($_POST['full-info']) && isset($_POST['posters']) && isset($_POST['screenshots']) && isset($_POST['trailers']) && isset($_POST['gameplays']) && isset($_POST['author']))
```

Instead of manually checking to see if each object has been set in the `$_POST` array, you can just iterate through `$_POST`.

Create an array of the variables that you need to be set:

```
$req_fields = array(

    'title', 
    'main-poster', 
    'type', 
    'year', 
    'language', 
    'platform', 
    'publisher', 
    'size', 
    'graphics', 
    'little-info', 
    'full-info', 
    'posters', 
    'screenshots', 
    'trailers', 
    'gameplays', 
    'author'

);
```

Then create an array for the elements that haven't been set:

```
$notset = array();
```

Finally, iterate through `$_POST` checking to see if each value is set. If not, add it to the array.

```
foreach ($req_fields as $key) {

    if (!isset($_POST[$key]) {

        $notset[] = $key;

    }
}
```

Then check to see if any values have not been set and redirect the user, else, load the model and echo the post:

```
if (count($notset) > 0) {

    $this->load->view('postnews');

}
else {

    $this->load->model('Gamesmodel');
    echo $this->Gamesmodel->PostArticle($title, $main_poster, $type, $year, $language, $platform, $publisher, $size, $graphics, $little_info, $full_info, $posters, $screenshots, $trailers, $gameplays, $autor, $date);

}
```

Presumably the actual reason behind the insert not working is because it isn't actually called. The reason behind this would be that some of the keys were not actually set.

Iterate through the `$notset` array to see if this is the case:

```
foreach ($notset as $unsetField) {

    echo "Field {$unsetField} is not set. <br />";

}
```

Comment: thank you, thank you and thank you again very much to check my code. I am sure other "noobs" who has same problems will be glad to see the answer.